# Getting an error in a nested IF statement in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested, conditional-statements

I used a slightly complicated if statement for a simple algorithm to find the smallest positive number, compare it with a certain number and then return it in a another number in a certain column. However I get an error saying that i should add an apostrophe. Is there a syntax error here? I am new to excel and I wanted someone more with more expertise to check. Here is my code.

```
=IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=C2,I2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=J2,D2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=K2,E2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=L2,F2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=M2,G2,A2)))))
```

Comment: Break out each nested `IF` into different cells and get each one working properly before putting them together. I don't know what you're trying to do but it's pretty clear that the first nested `IF` is invalid syntax, in a few ways: `MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))` ... you can't check if a range of cells is greater than zero,  maybe you meant to sum? Also the IF has no 3rd parameter so it will return FALSE if not true.  ...also this isn't really a programming question. (See "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve]. Maybe SuperUser would be appropriate.)

Comment: Your formula is not working because, `=IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=C2,I2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=J2,D2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=K2,E2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=L2,F2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:02))=M2,G2,A2)))))` instead of `O` you have used `0` so it should be `=IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,""))=C2,I2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,""))=J2,D2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,""))=K2,E2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,""))=L2,F2,IF(MIN(IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,""))=M2,G2,A2)))))`

Comment: @ashleedawg OP has mistakenly used `0` in place of `O` for each `TRUE` value `I2:02` which should be `I2:O2`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya - That too....(good eye, that can be tricky to spot!) I think there are several problems, like using  `[range of cells]>0`.

Comment: @ashleedawg if i am not wrong, i dont understand what is the use of that formula, however it worked for me and gave me a random number. And IF(I2:O2>0,I2:O2,"") this works and only gives a spilled range of values when wrapped within MIN it gives the MIN Value, otherwise i dont understand the use of this formula

Comment: @ashleedawg yeah it was tricky, i was repeatedly tryin the formula as is posted by OP, to my amaze i found that the `0` part is not highlighted which triggered me and when replaced the same with `O` it worked. !

Comment: @ashleedawg and i think OP should have resolved the same, on his own instead of posting a query here, he could have identified his typo error, !

Comment: Well, the I am no longer getting the error making after making that correction of replacing 0 with O. Its a simple pogram. I have a list of numbers from I2 to O2 . I am trying to find the least positive number among them. After i find that number by MIN, i match to all numbers in the original list. Whenever that if statement is true, i replace a number in my formula column with another number.

Comment: @SyedTallayHaidar hope you are able to fix the issue now, i think you could have done that on your own, with some perseverance!

Comment: i was trying it for an hour beforehand. I couldnt do it thats why i came here.

Comment: @SyedTallayHaidar alright no issues Sir, i understand it was a typo, even i was dumbfounded for sometime! Was unable to differentiate between `0` and `O`

Comment: The solution was pretty simple all i needed to do was press shift+clt+enter and it worked

Comment: @SyedTallayHaidar yes if you are not using `Excel 2021` or `O365` then you need to press `CSE` otherwise, you don't need it!